# Security of a ro volume in Docker

Tags: sandbox, docker, kernel

What are the security implications of mapping a host folder to a Docker container ro? For example `-v /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:ro`.

Of course, the container can now read the host folder.  But, assuming the mapping is of data that's public, does the ro mapping increase the attack surface? It would seem to me that any container escape that could be done with such a mapping could be done without it.  Is there any case where a ro mapping makes an escape possible?

Comment: I find your example confusing, because `/usr/local/bin` contains executables and many of them dynamically linked so you would probably need to map some library folders containing the required shared libraries in the same manner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case an `ro` mapping shouldn't increase the liklihood of breakout but there's two exceptions I can think of

- Unix sockets (e.g. the Docker socket) are still accessible when mounted read-only. Mounting the docker socket allows for trivial container breakout, other sockets would depend on what they can do.
- The [Dirty Pipe Vulnerability](https://blog.aquasec.com/cve-2022-0847-dirty-pipe-linux-vulnerability) from early 2022 allows for files mounted read-only in a container to be overwritten, so mounting things that way on a vulnerable host would allow the files to be overwritten from inside the container.